# Is there a reason my instance variables (self) are not being saved when going between Test Case in Robot?

Tags: python, robotframework

I currently have Python 3.7.3 with robotframework 3.1.1 and created a Python library (MySite.py) like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from collections import namedtuple
from HomePage import *

class Pages(object):
    def __init__(self, handle):
        self._pages = {}
        self._home_window = handle
        pass

    @property
    def home_window(self):
        return self._home_window

    @home_window.setter
    def home_window(self, v):
        self._home_window = v

    @property
    def homePage(self):
        return self._pages['home']

    def add(self, name, page):
        self._pages[name] = page

    def get(self, name):
        return self._pages[name]

    def getPages(self):
        return self._pages

class MySite(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._driver = None

    @property
    def driver(self):
        return self._driver

    @driver.setter
    def driver(self, v):
        self._driver = v

    def close_all_windows(self):
        # Close all windows
        pages = self.pages.getPages()
        for name, page in pages.items():
            page.close()

    def open_my_page(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie("IEDriverServer_Win32_3.141.0\\IEDriverServer.exe")

        # Define pages
        self.pages = Pages(self.driver.current_window_handle)
        self.pages.add('home', HomePage(self.driver, self.pages))

        # Open browser
        self.driver.get(www.mypage.com)

        # Code to wait to finish loading the page
```

When I create a Robot script to open and close the browser in one test case, it works:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    MySite.py

*** Test Case ***
Open Browser to mypage.com and close browser
    Open My Page
    Close All Windows
```

But when I create a Robot script to open a browser in one test case and then on another test case to close it I get AttributeError: 'MySite' object has no attribute 'pages':

```
*** Settings ***
Library    MySite.py

*** Test Case ***
Open Browser to mypage.com
    Open My Page

Close Browser
    Close All Windows
```

It seems like my instance variables are not being saved off for the second robot test. Do you know why this may be? Or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know anything about Robot scripts, but in general, test cases are independent of each other.  It makes no sense to create an internal object in one test case and expect it to still exist in the next test case.  If you have elements that depend on each other, put them all into one test case.

Comment: The other option to @JohnGordon statement is make a test class to remember state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a new instance of the library is created for each test. You need to set the scope such that an instance of the class is created once for each suite or once for each test run.

This is mentioned in the user guide, in a section titled [Test Library Scope](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope):

> Test libraries can control when new libraries are created with a class attribute ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE. This attribute must be a string and it can have the following three values:
>
> **TEST CASE**
>   A new instance is created for every test case. A possible suite setup and suite teardown share yet another instance. **This is the default.**
>
> TEST SUITE
>   A new instance is created for every test suite. The lowest-level test suites, created from test case files and containing test cases, have instances of their own, and higher-level suites all get their own instances for their possible setups and teardowns.
>
> GLOBAL
>   Only one instance is created during the whole test execution and it is shared by all test cases and test suites. Libraries created from modules are always global.

(emphasis mine)

To set the scope to "TEST SUITE" so that the instance is created only once for the whole suite, you would start your class definition like this:

```
class MySite(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'
```